What is the most recent version of Docker Desktop that allows reverting to compose V1?
I have recently upgraded my Docker Desktop to v4.29.0. The container setup I'm running doesn't work with Compose V2 and so previously I have unchecked the "Use Docker Compose V2" checkbox in Desktop settings to revert back to using compose V1. Like this:

The issue I have is the Desktop v4.29.0 settings page no longer seems to have this option, and my containers fail to run because Compose V2 is now being used.
What is the most recent version of of Docker Desktop that still allows this reverting to Compose V1?
I had a quick dig in the Desktop release notes but couldn't find a "dropped support for Compose V1" message or anything like that.

4.23.0
Removed

Removed Compose V1 from Docker Desktop as it has stopped receiving updates. Compose V2 has replaced it and is now integrated into all current Docker Desktop versions. For more information, see Migrate to Compose V2.

Reference: Docker Desktop 4.23.0 release notes

Perfect! I uninstalled 4.29.0, downloaded 4.22.1 for here and the option re-appeared :)
